# Загрузка софта в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Вчера поставил убунту на комп. Загрузил из центра приложений несколько прог. А сейчас не могу. При установке пишет: "проверьте соединение с интернетом" (хотя инт есть). Есть предположение, что тут намудрил что-то админ в мое отсутствие. Можно ли как-то узнать, что и как у меня закрыт доступ?

Comment: такую же ошибку выдает когда недоступен какой-то источник (software source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню вышесказанное, если вы работаете через прокси, то установлен ли прокси можно посмотреть в файле

```
nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

там должно быть что-то вроде:

```
Acquire::https::proxy "https://10.0.1.11:8080/";
```

список репозиториев можно посмотреть командой

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

получите:

```
deb http://[Зеркало]/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick restricted main multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates restricted main multiverse universe
```

[] Тут у вас может быть адрес зеркала, если вы соединяетесь с интернетом не на прямую

Answer (score 1):

Если доступ к настройкам закрыт, то терзайте админа.  Если у вас есть прокси-сервер, то вполне возможно, что он указан только для браузера и соответственно остальная система не может достучатся, куда надо.